# JavaScript -- Validating a Certain Number of Inputs

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have 8 form inputs that are asking for either 8 half-day activity dates or, 4 fullday dates.

I collected all of the `input values` and put them into an array, and to test the collection process, wrote the following function that just says if ALL the inputs are empty, keep a button disabled and if ALL are full, enable the button.

```
function checkMeetings()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < meetings.length; i++)
        {
            if(meetings[i] === "" || meetings[i] === null)
            {
                meetingsCanSubmit = false;
            }
            else
            {
                meetingsCanSubmit =  true;
            }
        }        
    }
    checkMeetings();
```

That test worked fine.

What I'd like to do is create a counter that counts the number of input boxes that have been filled in and when it gets to at `>= 4` enable the button. (In reality it won't enable the button it's going to run a secondary function but for the purposes of this example I'm keeping it simple.)

Since the for loop is counting via the i++ anyways, I tried something to the effect of

`if(meetings[i] <= 4)` do the following, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.  Should I be setting up a second counter within my if-statement?

Comment: Do you store value in array if inputs are empty? If yes then what do you store in array when value is empty?

Comment: That function works fine only if there's one element in `meetings`. It sets the flag based on the last element only.

Comment: @DhavalSoni that's actually a great question, and one I hadn't thought of.  Would it be better to store the value regardless of the content but create a variable counter for empty values and one for non-null values and then just compare?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner I would recommended that don't store empty value in array if its not require. Then you have to simply check length of array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()`, check the `.length` of resulting array

```
var meetingsCanSubmit = meetings.filter(function(input) {
                          return input !== "" && input != null
                        }).length >= 4;

if (meetingsCanSubmit) {
  // do stuff
}
```